# How do I call the MVC3 validation javascript in my own jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that has a link that fires off some ajax and passes through the value of a text box. I would like to be able to cause the same validation on that text box that would occur if I had clicked submit (and preferably without any changing of the standard javascript) but not fire off the validation for everything else in the form that has validation.

Is there a particular function that I need to call on the click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC3 uses the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation).
Call `$('form selector').validate().form()`.

Comment: From reading that page, it's actually `$('form').validation().element('selector')` but thanks for the link.